# Oracle Apex 20.1 error after login, session has expired

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Using Apex 20.1 with Oracle DB XE 18c on Windows.
After installing any productivity App and after adding username and password and login to the application, an error appears: "Your session has expired, Click here to create a new session."
I tried many times to reinstall them without any good. The same message appears after login, and I can't run the application.
This is not Session Timeout error.
Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution the problem was with the firefox browser security with ORA_WWV_PACKAGED_APPLICATIONS whitch make him i think prevent the user/site cookies.
Once i add exception to the firefox security for Apex URL, it didn't happen again.